# data recovery on image following https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Tags: data-recovery, forensics

I made an image of an usb stick which was mistakenly made into a live usb with xubuntu in it. The unit is 8GB, the xubuntu.iso 1.3GB. I only want to work with the image and I think each command I try from https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery fails because I dont know how to rewrite commands to make em work on the image file.

Prior to the formatting, the usb stick had:

1. The ISO copy of Xubuntu 17.04 64 bits, the last addition to the usb stick
2. Portable apps with several apps (Firefox, geany, the whole and latest Libreoffice, Vlc, Unetbooting)
3. A part of the usb was used both by xubuntu and windows OS. Here were the files that I care about, specifically a directory with several text files (opened with geany, so no .txt files, but simply a file without a format append like .txt or .odp). These files are no longer than 15KB, where several usernames and passwords were stored. The directorys' name is basic or Basic.

The Image file is in a directory named 'Damaged-USB'. I always cd to it and try to execute commands from there.

If I execute:

```
output of sudo foremost -i damaged-usb.img -o /Damaged-USB/foremost
```

terminal starts to print output, like

> foundat=locale/nl/bprivacy.properties�WKnG��%md"�8Y
>                                                            �$ہ�$Bm�3ř�݃�R���H.�m���$y��!���d�M����{���B�߸�����������?��}I�'�������!=+�-�1*T�iʱ�T�*��1̾�{Nc:�͜�|��X�t�x��˧?��(��<��zɝ�k^�a�l�PQ�[��١�t4�]<�*��%�
>   foundat=locale/he/bprivacy.properties�V�n�F}�W����4�S
>   B�+�����v��S�`kc�;anifest.mf��Ǯ��@��5���-��'q�<�l1_�n���p�.b�đX����ZԕY:�_�t�ʾ��3������o��n����:&�'�̿���˹h��>k��>����7_���o�iP��/�D�ς
>                     (�j���=/`j�*����cߦ*��`V�i����Ī�p��(�{wqpD�=��$V���ܓ}Mp����洛A&��t4�r���k1��/�@{���oU��قI����a�\�{������|I;�d�w㺟��\�$���cLq��r�*���$y���
>                                                                                                                                                                        ���3��@�:��S!n��
>                                                                                                                                                                                         ����t�pSM�L!��Ts�.�n��7%��
>   i�L4�{���m\�&�����+;:������L����χ0L���������zN��n(=��9�'�c�׏�,>���oِ�
>
>                          ��¾
>                             ��GB�Xƞ@w��G�;�(j foundat=META-INF/mozilla.sf
>   1�'�z�$0�3��u1�u�LO-.��M��L2�*�3����3�K��ͣ�]�L���mm��=
>          ������{�x�[�T�Ugg��rq foundat=META-INF/mozilla.rsa�WgTS��e'!��

but then, after less than a minute, it suddenly stops, and the output is not printed anywhere in the directory (I always work from 'Damaged-USB')

Another example: if I execute

`sudo foremost -t jpg -i damaged-usb.img`

it starts to look for jpg files but then, it stops after just 26 seconds. For a 8GB unit thats a bit too fast. Thus I suspect the command was aborted.

Third, I also don't know if the processes listed https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery are to be followed like a list: First Extract filesystem from recovered image (which I also did not achieve), and then Extract individual files from recovered image, or you can just go directly to extract individual files without extracting a filesystem.

mmls output is:

```
mmls damaged-usb.img 
DOS Partition Table
Offset Sector: 0
Units are in 512-byte sectors

      Slot      Start        End          Length       Description
000:  Meta      0000000000   0000000000   0000000001   Primary Table (#0)
001:  -------   0000000000   0000002047   0000002048   Unallocated
002:  000:000   0000002048   0015556607   0015554560   Win95 FAT32 (0x0b)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is that `foremost` looks at the start of the image file, detects an undamaged file system (the Xubuntu imgae) in which there is nothing to find.

But it should look behind this image only. `foremost` knows the option `-s` by which you can skip blocks (512 bytes by default). So you should calculate how many blocks the Xubuntu image covers and make `foremost` skip these.

Comment: So you should calculate how many blocks the Xubuntu image covers and make foremost skip these... and how do I calculate that? Simply multiplying 1.3GBx512? Is there an irc for foremost?

Comment: @green3 Math is hard... You have to divide 1,300,000,000 bytes by 512. I don't know what you mean by "irc".

Comment: internet relay chat, where I can ask a community about it